# source directory specification in maven

Tags: maven, sass

I have tried to give the source directory in a sass plugin. when i tried the command: mvn install it is showing build success if i give the directory as shown in below

{

```
<plugin>
                <groupId>nl.geodienstencentrum.maven</groupId>
                <artifactId>sass-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.17</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                    <phase>prepare-package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>update-stylesheets</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                <resources>
                <resource>
                <source>
<directory>${project.basedir}/web/VAADIN/themes/styling/*.scss</directory>
                </source>
                <destination>${project.basedir}/web/VAADIN/themes/styling/*.css</destination>
                </resource>
                </resources>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
```

}

but it is showing the error like specified sourcedirectory web/VAADIN/themes.... does not exist

if i give the directory with the total file name as themes/styling/scheduling.scss it is showing build failure....

can anyone suggest me how to give that source directory. i am new to maven. my .scss file is in web/VAADIN/themes/styling/scheduling.scss

Comment: I would recomment to read the documentation http://www.geodienstencentrum.nl/sass-maven-plugin/update-stylesheets-mojo.html

Comment: thanks for the response khmarbaise.Itried that one also.I have added the below code by replacing previous one <source>
 <directory>${project.basedir}/web/VAADIN/themes/styling</directory>
          <includes>
                 <include>*.scss</include>
             </includes>
       </source>
       <relativeOutputDirectory>..</relativeOutputDirectory>
       <destination>${project.build.directory}/web/VAADIN/themes/styling/styles.css</destination>  it is showing the error like Failed to execute goal nl.geodienstencentrum.maven:sass-maven-plugin:2.17:update-stylesheets (default) on project